# Flask update image without page refresh

Tags: python, html, flask, web, caching

I am trying to display a picture that changes whenever I move a slider.

I'm doing this to change the name of the photo whenever I move a slider that controls `slice_selection` and sends it in a `AJAX GET` request.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.imshow(ct_array[slice_selection], clim=(-1000, 3000), cmap='gray')
new_graph_name = "graph_" + str(time.time()) + ".png"
  for filename in os.listdir(pathToStatic):
     if filename.startswith('graph_'):  # not to remove other images
        os.remove(os.path.join(pathToStatic, filename))
plt.savefig(os.path.join(pathToStatic, new_graph_name))

return render_template('lung_view.html', title='Lung cancer view', form=form, graph=new_graph_name)
```

It works fine, the old file is deleted and the new file has the correct image.

**HTML**

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=graph) }}" />
```

After render_template the image doesn't change, even though it is no longer or disk so I tried the following things:

`SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT = 0` in app config

```
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, public, max-age=0"
    response.headers["Expires"] = 0
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    return response
```

Disabled cache in F12->Network

Tried using redirect instead of render_template.

Adding dummy ? to src like this:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=graph) }}?dummy=8484744" />
```

I don't know what else to do, it feels like nothing is working and I exhausted all the options.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: if you send AJAX, then JavaScript has to get result from server and replace it in HTML. Or simpler: server should send only name of new image and JavaScript should replace this name in `<img>` in browser - and then browser will load image automatically. You don't have to send all HTML when you use JavaScript.

Comment: The partial refresh and DOM manipulation should be done in JavaScript. I don't believe it is something that can be done by Flask with Jinja since the HTML only can be sent once by the response from the server.